# Can I apply script in css?

Tags: css

The first two pairs of curly braces are inside a string, and do not mark the end of the selector.

[This is a valid CSS 2.1 rule.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html)

```
p[example="public class foo\
{\
    private int x;\
\
    foo(int x) {\
        this.x = x;\
    }\
\
}"] { color: red }
```

This would be really very very useful if someone can give me an example of using such script in css.

Comment: Never seen anything like this before.

Comment: Yes, I was too, so just confused about this, just check the provided link....

Comment: While CSS's attribute selector would work to match against an attribute value containing a script (or newlines), the practicality of your example is very limited.

Comment: @Dai can you show me a working example?

Comment: There is no “script” being “used in CSS” here – that is simply a selector what targets a `p` element that has an `example` attribute with that content …

Comment: That example just shows you what gets ignored in CSS. Read the entire page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, here's your example: [**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nnqtadks/2/)

```
<p example="public class foo{    private int x;    foo(int x) {        this.x = x;    }}">
    test text
</p>
```

css:

```
p[example="public class foo\
{\
    private int x;\
\
    foo(int x) {\
        this.x = x;\
    }\
\
}"] { color: red }
```

Just don't ask me why on earth someone would ever want to use this... I believe the purpose of the w3 docs was to show that you can write multiline attribute selector...

Comment: pass subliminal messages to the user through as part of a new marketing conspiracy maybe?

Comment: is \ for multiline separator?

Comment: Actually \ means to consider the following line-break as if it was in the same line...

Comment: @C-link Nepal: Didn't you read the spec that prompted this question to begin with?